# Any unregistered user can login (PHP)

Tags: php, authentication

I'm working on a login for my website, when I login it doesn't check to see if the user already exists in the database. It allows anyone to sign in even if you haven't registered.

This is the code for the login.

```
<?php


     //database details
      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "myname";
      $password = "******";
      $dbname = "mydb";


      // Create connection
      $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
      session_start();        

      if(isset($_POST['email']))

    {
        $email = $_POST ['email'];
        $password =$_POST ['password'];


        $query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email='$email' AND Password='$password'";


        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);





         if($result==1)
        {

           header('Location: profile.php');
           exit();
        }

        else
        {

       header('Location: failedlogin.html');
       exit();
        }


    }
```

?>

Comment: 1. SQL injection. 2. don't store plaintext passwords in DB! 3. `$result` returns `true/false`, not the number of rows.

Comment: `mysqli_query()` returns true on success. Meaning the query has no errors.. Also I hope this code isn't on the live server. SQL injection is waiting to happen

Comment: And also, please dont save password as is. You can use `password_hash`

Comment: *"It allows anyone to sign in even if you haven't registered."* ... that's actually what you're telling it to do...

Comment: Could you provide sample code example of how to do it right please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code never checks if the user account exists in the database. It only checks if the query was executed without error. This should work(untested):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email='$email' AND Password='$password' LIMIT 1";
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)){

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

        //user account exists
        $member = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $email = $member["Email"];

    } else {

        //user account does not exist

    }

} else {

    echo "Error executing database query.";

}
```